How to Reset Context Data on Browser Back Button Navigation in React Multi-Step Form?
I'm working on a multi-step form in a React application, where currentStepData is stored in a shared context (StepperContext). Each step has its own data structure, and currentStepData updates accordingly when moving forward. However, I am facing an issue when using the browser back button.
When navigating from GuestDetailsStepView to UserExperienceStepView, currentStepData is updated to hold data specific to UserExperienceStepView. But when I use the browser back button to return to GuestDetailsStepView, currentStepData still holds UserExperienceStepView's data instead of resetting to the data for GuestDetailsStepView.
Expected Behavior:
currentStepData should reset to GuestDetailsStepView's data when navigating back to this component using the browser back button.
Current Behavior:
currentStepData retains the data from UserExperienceStepView, causing GuestDetailsStepView to display incorrect information.
GuestDetailsStepView Component:
export const GuestDetailsStepView = () => {
  const intl = useIntl();
  const { currentStepData } = useContext(StepperContext);  // Line A
  const guestDetailsStepData = currentStepData as GuestInfoStepData;
};

UserExperienceStepView Component:
export const UserExperienceStepView = () => {
  const intl = useIntl();
  const { getStepData, currentStepData, setCurrentStepData, navigateToStep, setStepperLoading } =
    useContext(StepperContext); 

  const guestDetailsStepData = getStepData<GuestDetailsStepData>('guestDetailsStep');  
  const userExperienceStepData = currentStepData as ExperienceStepData;  // Line B
};

Is there an efficient way to handle currentStepData to ensure it reflects the correct step's data when navigating back with the browser back button? Any advice on managing context state in this scenario would be greatly appreciated!
